# Batch File removes one % symbol when echoing to a text file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch file write the command

```
for /L %%f in (10,-1,0) do MD Items%%f
```

to another batch file but on that new batch file the command gets changed to

```
   for /L %f in (10,-1,0) do MD Items%f
```

and you need two % symbols when using the `For` command in a batch file

heres what the script is

```
echo %userprofile%\desktop > "Folder Generator1.bat"

echo for /L %%f in (10,-1,0) do MD Items%%f >> "Folder Generator1.bat"
```

how do I make it so the echo command doesn't change any of the code

Comment: Have you tried adding more `%` so that they instead get consumed by `cmd` and keep the ones you intend? `:)`

Comment: `%userprofile\desktop%` with or without a trailing space is not a valid command for your `Folder Generator1.bat` to run!

Comment: yea I tried using 3-5 of the % symbols but it juts got changed to 1

Comment: thanks so much using more did work

Answer (score 3):

To write a literal `%`, you have to escape it with another `%`. It's not just for `for` metavariables, but also for "normal" variables. To literally write `%%`, you have to escape each of it with another `%` (and end up with `%%%%`):

```
echo cd /d "%%userprofile%%\desktop" > "Folder Generator1.bat"
echo for /L %%%%f in (10,-1,0) do MD Items%%%%f >> "Folder Generator1.bat"
```

Be aware, there are other "poison characters" (`<>|&`) that have to be escaped with a caret `^` (`%` is the only exception):

```
echo echo Hello ^| find "ll" >> second.bat
echo echo hello ^& echo world >> second.bat
echo echo hello ^>^> file.txt >> second.bat
```

Depending on the context, there are even more characters that have to be escaped: `),";=^` and from time to time even spaces.

(and to make it not *too* easy, `findstr` introduces its own escape and poison chars)

Suggestion: you write an additional space at the end of each line. To avoid that_

```
 >file.txt echo no trailing space here.
```

(you *could* also write `echo something>file.txt, but that *will* bite you someday - whenever the string to redirect ends with a single digit, so don't make this a habit)

Suggestion: if you want to write several lines to the same file, use `

```
(
  echo @echo off
  echo echo username=%%username%%
  echo echo (attention with parentheses^)
) > second.bat
```

Attention: the `)` has to be escaped, else it will close the code block too early (I *did* mention escaping is context dependent).

Comment: @everyone: feel free to extend the lists, should I have forgotten some poison chars (quite sure, I did)

Comment: You'd need to escape carets themselves Stephan, but the rules for doing so may not be simple enough to just add them to your answer. Additionally, as you can see in my answer, using nested parentheses, means that the internal ones require escaping too. _(sorry, you added that as a later edit)_

Comment: @Compo: yes, the caret... of course. I guess it fits as "Context-dependent"

Answer (score 0):

Given my comment under your question itself, I'd suggest you were looking for something a little more like this:

```batch-file
@(  Echo @Echo %%UserProfile%%\Desktop
    Echo @For /L %%%%G In (10 -1 0^) Do @MD Items%%%%G
) 1> "Folder Generator1.bat"
```

Or:

```batch-file
@(  Echo @CD /D "%%UserProfile%%\Desktop" 2^> NUL ^|^| Exit /B
    Echo @For /L %%%%G In (10 -1 0^) Do @MD Items%%%%G
) 1> "Folder Generator1.bat"
```

Or possibly even:

```batch-file
@(Echo @For /L %%%%G In (10 -1 0^) Do @MD "%%UserProfile%%\Desktop\Items%%%%G") 1> "Folder Generator1.bat"
```

As you can see in the examples above, because it's nested within a parenthesized block, you also need to escape the internal closing parentheses with carets, *(which falls somewhere outside of Stephans list)*.